# VBA vlookup within loop row and column

Tags: vba, excel, loops, lookup

Excuse me , I want to ask about looping use `vlookup` for row and column. This is my code, but didn't work. can you help to correct this code. Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN")

With ws
    For j = 3 To 100
        For i = 2 To 600
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN").Cells(i, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT KUANTITATIF").Range("A:AC"), j + 3, 0) = "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN").Cells(i, j) = 0

            Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN").Cells(i, j) = (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN").Cells(i, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT KUANTITATIF").Range("A:AC"), j + 4, 0) / Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN").Cells(i, 1), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT KUANTITATIF").Range("A:AC"), j + 3, 0)) - 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have declared variable `ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN")`, you don't need to repeat `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN")` all the time in your code. You can use this variable instead, i.e.: `ws.Cells(i, j) = 0`. Your code will be much more readible.

Comment: "Didn't work" in what way exactly? BTW it would be more efficient to use Match to get the correct result row, then use that in direct cell references instead of looking up the same value multiple times.

Comment: This code didn't work if I loop for both coloumn and row, but it does work if I loop for only row or coloumn.

Comment: This code didn't work if I loop for both coloumn and row, but it does work if I loop for only row or coloumn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use "on error resume next" in your code. Please set your worksheet and set your range too for easy understanding

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN")
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT KUANTITATIF")


With ws
    For j = 3 To 100
        For i = 2 To 600

        On Error Resume Next



            If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Range("A:AC"), j + 3, 0) = "" Then
            ws.Cells(i, j) = 0

            Else


            ws.Cells(i, j) = (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Range("A:AC"), j + 4, 0) / Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Range("A:AC"), j + 3, 0)) - 1


            End If


        Next i
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be more efficient:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim wsTable               As Worksheet
    Dim i                     As Long
    Dim j                     As Long
    Dim vMatch

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GROWTH PERUSAHAAN")
    Set wsTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT KUANTITATIF")

    With ws
        For i = 2 To 600

            vMatch = Application.Match(ws.Cells(i, 1), wsTable.Range("A:A"), 0)
            ' if lookup value isn't found, skip
            If Not IsError(vMatch) Then
                For j = 3 To 100

                    If wsTable.Cells(vMatch, j + 3).Value2 = "" Then
                        ws.Cells(i, j).Value2 = 0

                    Else
                        ws.Cells(i, j).Value2 = (wsTable.Cells(vMatch, j + 4).Value2 / wsTable.Cells(vMatch, j + 3).Value2) - 1
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```